# how can i fix "No module named tensorflow.python.saved_model.model_utils"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow and luminoth for table detection.

In this command I used for training process

```
lumi dataset transform --type csv --data-dir data/ --output-dir tfdata/ --split train.csv --split val.csv --only-classes=table"
```

system shows [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zobc.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\lumi.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "site-packages\luminoth\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from luminoth.cli import cli  # noqa
  File "site-packages\luminoth\cli.py", line 14, in <module>
    from luminoth.eval import eval
  File "site-packages\luminoth\eval.py", line 8, in <module>
    from luminoth.datasets import get_dataset
  File "site-packages\luminoth\datasets\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .datasets import get_dataset  # noqa
  File "site-packages\luminoth\datasets\datasets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from luminoth.datasets.object_detection_dataset import ObjectDetectionDataset
  File "site-packages\luminoth\datasets\object_detection_dataset.py", line 3, in <module>
    from luminoth.datasets.base_dataset import BaseDataset
  File "site-packages\luminoth\datasets\base_dataset.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sonnet as snt
  File "site-packages\sonnet\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from sonnet.python import custom_getters
  File "site-packages\sonnet\python\custom_getters\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from sonnet.python.custom_getters import bayes_by_backprop
  File "site-packages\sonnet\python\custom_getters\bayes_by_backprop.py", line 97, in <module>
    _OK_PZATION_TYPE = tf.contrib.distributions.FULLY_REPARAMETERIZED
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 61, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 44, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import distribute
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\distribute\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.distribute.python.tpu_strategy import TPUStrategy
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\distribute\python\tpu_strategy.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.ops import tpu_ops
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu.keras_support import tpu_model as keras_to_tpu_model
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\tpu\keras_support.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu import tpu
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\tpu\tpu.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import xla
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\compiler\xla.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python import estimator
  File "site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    import tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.estimator_lib
  File "site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator_lib.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.baseline import BaselineClassifier
  File "site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\baseline.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib
  File "site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\model_fn.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.export import export_lib
  File "site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\export\export_lib.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.saved_model.model_utils import build_all_signature_defs
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.model_utils'
```

how can I fix this error????

Comment: How did you install these packages? Which version of Tensorflow and Luminoth did you install?

Comment: tensor flow version is 1.13.1 and luminoth version is 0.2.3

Comment: i install these packages in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 6):

According to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27079#issuecomment-478550943) I found by googling the error you got, you may be able to work around this by uninstalling and reinstalling the `tensorflow-estimator` package:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow_estimator
pip install tensorflow_estimator
```

I assume it's a conflict between files in the packages and their installation order matters.

Comment: I reinstalled, But again occur this error "luminoth.tools.dataset.readers.base_reader.InvalidDataDirectory: CSV annotation file not found. Should be located at `data/train.csv.csv"  i located correct path only  why occurs this error?

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: Yes, this is different question? how can i resolve it?

Comment: If my answer solved this particular problem, mark it as accepted, then ask your second question as a separate question.